# apache httpd using a lot of RAM memory and producing spikes in short time intervals

Tags: linux, memory, apache2, memory-usage

I have a problem with one of my servers.

Web server works well in 'normal' time period but one or two times per day there are spikes in RAM memory usage.

I put the Zabbix monitoring tool there, and got something like this from the server.

Those circled spikes are above 90% of RAM utilization that make problems

[zabbix_monitoring](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vg9P6.png)

Also, I put there my script for memory usage that gives me something like this as output.

```
 8954 elastic+  20   0 4948244 493160   6788 S   0.0 12.7   9:35.61 java
14076 apache    20   0  703616 275800   6152 S   0.0  7.1   0:05.56 httpd
13498 apache    20   0  703692 275744   6156 S   0.0  7.1   0:06.30 httpd
13441 apache    20   0  703716 275308   6128 S   0.0  7.1   0:06.37 httpd
15730 apache    20   0  703560 275168   6104 S   0.0  7.1   0:05.48 httpd
14068 apache    20   0  703628 275096   6076 S   0.0  7.1   0:05.32 httpd
14501 apache    20   0  703568 275084   6096 S   0.0  7.1   0:05.31 httpd
16593 apache    20   0  701348 272868   5512 S   0.0  7.0   0:04.52 httpd
10515 apache    20   0  700200 271988   6212 S   0.0  7.0   0:12.95 httpd
 4571 apache    20   0  441896  14236   6200 S   0.0  0.4   0:04.87 httpd
12083 apache    20   0  441860  12660   6136 S   0.0  0.3   0:02.07 httpd
  447 root      20   0   47652  12376  12248 S   0.0  0.3  20:11.71 systemd-jo+
```

And those apache RAM utilization comes from

```
14076 14536  7.1  0.2 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
13498 14536  7.1  0.2 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
13441 14536  7.0  0.2 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
15730 14536  7.0  0.5 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
14068 14536  7.0  0.2 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
14501 14536  7.0  0.3 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
16593 14536  7.0  0.9 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
```

In normal working conditions, I have this

```
  PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND
 8954 elastic+  20   0 4938960 471252  12868 S   0.0 12.1   5:01.40 java
23364 mysql     20   0 2894976 423432   2712 S   0.0 10.9   1331:14 mysqld
19880 apache    20   0  647864 219324   6084 S   0.0  5.7   0:06.17 httpd
19475 apache    20   0  446428  17884   6092 S   0.0  0.5   0:03.33 httpd
20327 apache    20   0  442796  13680   6048 S   0.0  0.4   0:00.43 httpd
```

Is there anything that I can do to prevent these spikes in RAM utilization?

In logs, there are not so unusual requests in those certain time periods.

Plus, if you are interested in my monitoring script written in bash you can clone it from:

https://github.com/milanpetrovic87/ram_memory_mail_notification

Comment: Additional information request from your spikey server, please. 
Any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server? 
Post on pastebin.com and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST; 
AND Optional very helpful information, if available includes -
htop OR top  for most active apps, 
ulimit -a       for a Linux/Unix list of limits, 
iostat -xm 5 3 for IOPS by device and core/cpu count, 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.